# lftp timeout not working

Tags: ftp

I am using the following command to set timeout of lftp command so that if the server is not available or is not accepting any new connection, the command ends after 10 sec.

```
lftp -e 'set ftp:passive-mode true; set net:timeout 10; cd /OUT; mput $filename; bye' -u mylftpuser,mypassword myhost.com
```

However, the timeout does not seem to work. When I run the above command on the command prompt, it retries connecting after 30 sec, 45 sect ..60 sec ...and never ends.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem with timeout not working when I used:

```
lftp -e "set net:timeout 5" -u user,pwd server
```

I have removed the `-e "set..."` part and use only `lftp -u user,pwd server` and the commands insert it into **~/.lftp/rc** file:

```
cat ~/.lftp/rc
set net:timeout 5
set net:max-retries 2
set net:reconnect-interval-base 5
```

This works fine for me now.

Comment: works for me, but my configuration file is `/etc/lftp.conf`

Answer (score 10):

Instead of `net:timeout 10`, try this:

```
set net:reconnect-interval-base 5; set net:max-retries 2;
```

Answer (score 8):

It's because of the very high default of `net:max-retries 1000` which is:

> the maximum number of sequential tries of  an  operation  without 
>   success. 0 means unlimited. 1 means no retries.

Change it (in your ***~/.lftp*** config file) to something like 5 and you're good to go.

Answer (score 1):

In the documentation you can find more information about the location of the settings and the available options. Below you can see the file locations of the settings.

On startup, lftp executes `~/.lftprc` and `~/.lftp/rc` (or `~/.config/lftp/rc` if `~/.lftp` does  not exist). You can place aliases and set commands there. Some people prefer to see full protocol debug, use `debug` to turn the debug on.

There is also a system-wide startup file in `/etc/lftp.conf`.  It can be  in  different  directory, see FILES section.